# I am trying to randomly generate jobs for the weighted job schedulling problem but it gives me an error

Tags: java, algorithm, job-scheduling

I am trying to randomly generate jobs for the weighted job schedulling problem but it gives me an error, the jobs are generated and it shows them when i print them, but when it tries to find the maximum value it gives an error

Code:

```
package classGenerator;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test1 {
// A job has start time, finish time and profit.
static class Job
{
    int start, finish, profit;
    Job(int start, int finish, int profit)
     {
        this.start = start;
        this.finish = finish;
        this.profit = profit;
     }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + "start='" + start + '\'' + "finish=" + finish + '\'' + "profit=" + profit + '}';
    }
}

static int latestNonConflict(Job arr[], int i)
{
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (arr[j].finish <= arr[i - 1].start)
            return j;
    }
    return -1;
}
 
// A recursive function that returns the maximum possible
// profit from given array of jobs. The array of jobs must
// be sorted according to finish time.
static int findMaxProfitRec(Job arr[], int n)
{
    // Base case
    if (n == 1) return arr[n-1].profit;
 
    // Find profit when current job is included
    int inclProf = arr[n-1].profit;
    int i = latestNonConflict(arr, n);
    if (i != -1)
    inclProf += findMaxProfitRec(arr, i+1);
 
    // Find profit when current job is excluded
    int exclProf = findMaxProfitRec(arr, n-1);
 
    return Math.max(inclProf, exclProf);
}
 
// The main function that returns the maximum possible
// profit from given array of jobs
static int findMaxProfit(Job arr[], int n)
{
    // Sort jobs according to finish time
    Arrays.sort(arr,new Comparator<Job>(){
       public int compare(Job j1,Job j2)
        {
           return j1.finish-j2.finish;
        }
       });
 
    return findMaxProfitRec(arr, n);
}
 
// Driver program
public static void main(String args[])
{
   int m = 4;
   Job arr[] = new Job[m];
   Random rand = new Random();
   for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       arr[i] = new Job(rand.nextInt(30),rand.nextInt(50),rand.nextInt(300));
       //System.out.println("Job[" + i + "]" + arr[i].toString());
   }
    int n =arr.length;
    System.out.println("The optimal profit is " + findMaxProfit(arr, n));
}
}
```

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
> at classGenerator.Test1.findMaxProfitRec(Test1.java:45)
> at classGenerator.Test1.findMaxProfitRec(Test1.java:47)

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of what the error means, or for someone to fix the defect in your code?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, i have never asked a question here before, i would like to understand why the error occurs, and how to fix it

Comment: The error occurs because your first recursive call `findMaxProfitRec(arr, i+1)` doesn't end up passing 1, or not soon enough, so that you get many recursive calls and run out of stack space.

Comment: Thank you, what should I do to avoid this?

Comment: Use the debugger and some printlns to understand what your algorithm is doing, and spot the problem. Don't use random data, find some input which causes the problem and keep using that until you fix it.